# Split the string based on a delimiter '.' . Have to ignore the delimiter in some cases such as numbering and abbreviations

Tags: python, string, split

I have a unique case, I have a list of strings in python. I want to split based on the delimiter `.` But in some cases `.` is used in the numbering like `1.2.3` or after abbreviations such as `vs.` or `Avg.`. Which I have to ignore.

Input string list:

```
 0  Avg. Txn Count/Card - Split by POI.Avg. Txn Count/Card - Split by POI.
 1  US SP Froecast (RC).US SP Froecast (RC).US SP Froecast (RC)
 2  Sector Analysis - Total Sector Sales vs. Portfolio.Sector Analysis Sector Sales vs. Portfolio.Sector Analysis
 3  H.3.3 Chargeback by MCC.H.3.3 Chargeback by MCC.H.3.3 Chargeback by MCC
 4  H.0 Average Spend and Ticket Metrics.H.0 Average Spend and Ticket Metrics
 5  Case 1.6: Geography wise CB POS.Case 1.6: Geography wise CB POS.
 6  Business Case 1.1.Business Case 1.1.Business Case 1.1
 7  1 - Overall picture_v2.1 - Overall picture_v2.1 - Overall picture
```

Expected output:

```
 0  Avg. Txn Count/Card - Split by POI
 1  US SP Froecast (RC)
 2  Sector Analysis - Total Sector Sales vs. Portfolio
 3  H.3.3 Chargeback by MCC
 4  H.0 Average Spend and Ticket Metrics
 5  Case 1.6: Geography wise CB POS
 6  Business Case 1.1
 7  1 - Overall picture_v2
```

I tried using regular expression but it's not working as expected. Please help me

```
 import re
 re.split(r',\s*(?!.*?])', string)
```

Comment: Do you have a full list of all cases where `.` is not supposed to be separator? If not this is a natual language processing job, that a simple regex cannot solve.

Comment: Yes. I have full list of all cases. I have specified all the cases above.  I tried NLTK sentence tokenizer. But it missed some cases.

Comment: For "the full lists of cases" you need to specify *all possible abbreviations* or it's not the full list.

Comment: Your output isn't splitting on `.`, it's giving only the first string after the split. Are you supposed to also be using the fact that each of them just duplicates the same string? Relatedly, do you really mean to split on the "." in "2.1" in the last one? This doesn't obey the numbering requirement (unless you're really looking for the duplication, and differentiating between "H.3.3" and "v2.1" because of the first period).

Comment: @AndrewJaffe That's not 2.1 its Overall picture_v2.  Then its `1 - Overall picture_v2`

Comment: @Arvinth, yes, we both know that, but that isn't correct from your rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `re.split` with `map`:

```
import re
content = [i.strip('\n') for i in open('filename.txt')]
result = [a for a, *_ in map(lambda x:re.split('(?<=[a-zA-Z\)\d])\.(?=[A-Z])|(?<=[a-zA-Z]\d)\.(?=\d)', x), content)]
print('\n'.join(result))
```

Output:

```
0  Avg. Txn Count/Card - Split by POI
1  US SP Froecast (RC)
2  Sector Analysis - Total Sector Sales vs. Portfolio
3  H.3.3 Chargeback by MCC
4  H.0 Average Spend and Ticket Metrics
5  Case 1.6: Geography wise CB POS
6  Business Case 1.1
7  1 - Overall picture_v2
```

Regex explanation:

`(?<=[a-zA-Z\)\d])\.(?=[A-Z])`: matches any instance of a `.`, preceded by an alphanumeric character, a `)`, or a digit, followed by a capital letter.

`|`: attempts to match either the expression to its left or right.

`(?<=[a-zA-Z]\d)\.(?=\d)`: matches any instance of a `.`, preceded by an alphanumeric character, a `)`, or a digit, followed by a digit. (i.e `picture_v2.1` should be split at the `.`)